# Support .NET 4.5 and DotNetCore

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, portable-class-library, .net-standard

How can I support .NET 4.5 and DotNetCore?

Is a PCL for shared code the best way forward (if at all possible to target DNX + .NET 4.5)?

Basically I have a library I publish as a NuGet package which still needs to support .NET 4.5.2, but I want to use this library in a DotNetCore application as well.

Is this something the .NET Standard will help with? Or is .NET standard only for .NET Core+?

Comment: _.NET Core_ is an implementation of the _.NET Standard_

Comment: i know, but wanted to know if .NET 4.5.2 implements a version of the standard, and it seems it does, but .NET Standard 1.5 doesn't suit my needs anyway :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET Core you can select your build target, and library used. All those changes are made in project.json.

To add support for .NET 4.52 you need to modify your project.json to look something like this

```
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": { //Support for .NET Core
  "imports": "dnxcore50",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  }
},
"net452": { //Support for .NET 452
}
```

To add platform specific code for .NET 452 use

```
#if NET452
...
#endif
```

To run with .NET 452 use this command

```
dotnet run -f NET452
```

On [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/packages) they have pretty good documentation about this topic and a lot of others.

This [Article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/) also explains very good how to manage Core and normal .NET code in one project.

Comment: Looks like I can change `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>` in the .csproj to `netcoreapp1.0;net452`

Comment: Note that   For multi-targeting TargetFramework will become TargetFrameworks (plural)